# How to use mapping column in criteria order by

Tags: hibernate, criteria

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Items.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("itemId", 1003));
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("category.categoryName"));
```

Here Category is ManyToOne Mapping .
Thanks!!

Comment: Please elaborate. Your query should return only one item. There is nothing to order.

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Items.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("itemId", 1003))
    .createAlias("category", "category")
    .addOrder(Order.desc("category.categoryName"));
```